# Slower response to AIX Virtual IP

Tags: unix, aix, oracle9i

Server_A is an AIX 5.3 server assigned 192.168.1.8.

TNS Ping to it's Oracle 9i DB instance was 120 msec.

A month later, Server_B with identical specs was built assigned 192.168.1.9.

Virtual IP 192.168.1.10 added to Server_A for "High Availability" reasons.

If Server_A goes offline, VIP will be re-assigned to Server_B manually.
TNS Ping returns much slower response time of 2 secs to the VIP.

Tnsnames.ora file on the client where TNS Ping is issued uses HOST = 192.168.1.10 so I don't believe /etc/resolv.conf on the AIX is relevant.

What are some possible areas and conf files to investigate?

EDIT: Is there network bindings order in AIX? My experience is more on Windows Servers. I'd appreciate thoughts about this angle.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aixnetworking/index.html

EDIT 2:
Unfortunately, network switches & routers are managed by another team who is not cooperating.
Good news is that application actually launches at comparable speeds with older server with lower HW specs.
    Old server: 4 Cores CPU / 32 GB RAM
    New server: 8 Cores CPU / 64 GB RAM

Initial testing describe in this post was done using Toad for Oracle >> Test Connections.
https://blog.toadworld.com/2017/12/14/getting-to-know-the-three-methods-of-connecting-to-the-database-using-toad-for-oracle-tns-direct-and-ldap

It logs into the Oracle DB and returns Connection Time. It surprised me to see 140 msec vs. 2 secs on Old vs. New server.
They're on the exact same subnet with same Default Gateway, network hops from client are identical.
Ping ms times looks good on both mostly 0 ms.

I don't know how concerned I should be with the Connection Times posted by Toad for Oracle.

Comment: The network has the old mac address for 192.168.1.10?  In that case, only the first ping should be slow.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I'll have the network team examine the ARP tables of switches/routers along the client-server path.

Comment: Rob, aren't you wasting your time? High availability and AIX 5.3/Oracle 9i ??

Comment: Gerard, Great point! Long story short...legacy App is to be replaced but it will take another 4 years.
The 15 year old app is EOL by vendor as you'd expect. No OS, DB, or App upgrades can be done as there is no guaranteed compatibility with current App version.
Focus is to have some sort of HA. Better than nothing.

Comment: Keep us posted, I've got at least 20 years experience doing just that.

Comment: Do you have these three lines in the client's `/etc/hosts` file: `192.168.1.8 Server_A; 192.168.1.9 Server_B; 192.168.1.10 Server_Vip` ?